# was VS. were after even though, even if, unless, wish et cetera

Tags: conditional-constructions, wish

***Comprehensively updated***

Thanks. Nonetheless, my specific question is something like this one:She came to terms with the fact that, **even though this was a bad situation**, *God does not make mistakes*, and He knit this baby fearfully and wonderfully within her daughter's womb ..

First off, could we write **were** instead of **was** in the bold part? if so, what is the different in the meaning?-- I think the probability would be stronger, wouldn't be? as I know you use both of was and were in conversation, but I think you could tell me how the meaning would change.

What is more, could you please explain in a more detailed way the bold and italic part?-- although I almost know what the sentence would mean, in fact, I still need your explanation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean about one form "having a connotation" and the other form somehow not having one?

Comment: Perhaps you could post this new question of yours as a separate thread, because right now the answer below reads strange due to your changing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even though this was a bad situation

Question: could we write were instead of was?

No, we cannot write "even though this *were* a bad situation".

"Even though" does not introduce *irrealis* or hypothetical here.  It introduces fact.  It is a bad situation. But *despite* the  bad situation, we cannot conclude that God "makes mistakes".

Comment: I have to araise this question in another froum

Answer (score 0):

> Even if it were/ was cold, we go.

There are a couple of things wrong here,  and the correct form depends on the meaning you want to convey.

First, "we go" indicates habitual action, something done regularly. If this is what you want you can say

> Even when it's cold, we go [for ice cream every Saturday afternoon].

If you really want to talk about a single event that's happening as you speak, then you have a tense disagreement between your two clauses. You need to express the conditional in the present also:

> Even if it is cold, we are going.

Note that "we are going" could indicate either ongoing action or something to happen in the very near future.